# \bar only allowed in math mode error

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am trying to type up an equation for my discrete math class but I keep on getting the "\bar allowed only in math mode" error. My previous usage of \bar worked out fine.

```
$p( \bar{E} \cap \bar{F}) = p( \bar{E \cup F})
= 1 - p(E \cup F)  = 1 - p(E) - p(F) + p(E \cap F)
= 1 - p(E) - p(F) + p(E)p(F\)  = (1-p(E))(1-p(F)) = p( \bar{E})p( \bar{F})$
```

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
$p( \bar{E} \cap \bar{F}) = p( \bar{E \cup F})
= 1 - p(E \cup F)  = 1 - p(E) - p(F) + p(E \cap F)
= 1 - p(E) - p(F) +
% -------------------
p(E)p(F\) %right here
% -------------------
= (1-p(E))(1-p(F)) = p( \bar{E})p( \bar{F})$
```

`p(E)p(F\)`. That's your problem. `\)` exits math mode. `\( ... \)` is an alternative to `$ ... $`. Where you've put `\)`, it's exited math mode. And then when you have `\bar` afterwards, you're outside of math mode, and:

```
\bar allowed only in math mode
```

If we correct that, then it compiles, however, `\bar{E \cup F}` is not going to work out very well, you probably want `\overline{E \cup F}`

Might I also recommend something more like:

```
\begin{flalign*}
  p(\bar{E} \cap \bar{F}) &= p(\,\overline{E \cup F}\,) \\[\parskip]
  &= 1 - p(E \cup F) \\[\parskip]
  &= 1 - p(E) - p(F) + p(E \cap F) \\[\parskip]
  &= 1 - p(E) - p(F) + p(E)p(F) \\[\parskip]
  &= (1-p(E))(1-p(F)) \\[\parskip]
  &= p(\bar{E})p(\bar{F})
\end{flalign*}
```

[image]

Comment: @fairyfantasy no problem, it's an easy mistake to make, if you invest in a good editor, hopefully the mistake will jump out more easily, as your syntax highlighting should show up that you're not in math mode anymore. Also, consider rethinking `\bar{E \cup F}`